# jsonschema2pojo is adding some attribute to parent class dynamically

Tags: java, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

I have a json schema like this:

```
{
  "JavaType:"com.a.b.c.MyClass",
  "extends": {
    "type": "object",
    "javaType": "com.a.b.MyBaseClass"
  }
}
```

After build is executed `jsonschema2pojo` is adding some attribute & setter/getter dynamically to `MyBaseClass` class. Is there a way we can stop this run time modification to this class? I just want this `MyBaseClass` to have nothing just a symbolic class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `existingJavaType` property instead of `javaType`.